# Ruby on Rails 3 : Trying to render a view from a different controller. But I get to the same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my app, I have created a form to create new posts (Post is a model). I have a controller with the name posts. The form is located in the admins controller. The form use the form_for(@post). It post to the post controller. In this method, the post gets created successfully. But the problem is with failed submissions. In the form, I have added the code to show the errors

```
    <% if @post.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                The form contains <%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                    <li> <%= msg %> </li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

But in the post controller, if there's a failed submission, I have set it to redirect_to the newpost page in the admins controller. When redirecting, I will loose the error messages.

So, I added

```
render 'dasharea/newpost'
```

localhost:3000/dasharea/newpost is the URL of the page that have the form. With this code, it say

```
Missing template dasharea/newpost with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.
```

But Im already in that page? Then I tried to add the controller and the action like this (note: im editing the create action of posts controller. I need to render the newpost action in admins controller) :

```
render 'admins/newpost'
```

Then, it will direct me to the posts :

```
http://localhost:3000/posts
```

But now, the form is there and I can see the errors. But I need to render the oroginal page which I have the form (dasharea/newpost)! How can I do this? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Try just adding `render :newpost`

Comment: @Max Now it say "Missing template posts/newpost" This will call newpost action in the same controller right? But I need to pint to a different controller.

Comment: Render is not calling an action, it is looking for the file and rendering.

Comment: @cpuguy83 So, how to get the right file for me?

Comment: @cpuguy83 did that :( render 'dasharea/newpost'. then it say Missing template dasharea/newpost. also tried "render 'admins/newpost'" (that take me to "posts")

Comment: Add a slash at the beginning

Comment: @cpuguy83 still the same issue :(

Comment: Then your path is wrong, or you don't have a file matching the mime-type

Comment: @cpuguy83 How to add it? The file is in /app/views/admins/newpost.html.erb

Comment: @EApubs try `render :partial => '/admins/newpost'`

Comment: After falled validation you're on /posts because the put or post request is made to that path. Then you have an exception to render 'newposts' because you are not being redirected, just rendering html. You could do a redirect to your new action but since you're object did not save, there would be nothing here. It's also another request on your server. If the url is important to you perhaps you could respond with javascript, and change the page location if it  saves, or display the errors via javascript if it does not.

Comment: you should post relevant controller code / routes here. You clearly have a controller issue, so it's hard to answer with only view code and some bits of "render".

Comment: Have you added gem for prototype actions on the controller for the rails 3.2.X version ? if not how are you getting render template on the controller side? You have to use js file to return that perticular  page you can get on the view page only `render :partial => ...` if you are updating from controller you have to `render :text/js/ => ` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution: AJAX form. No more issues. Update the form on the spot with javascript. You can even redirect using `window.location.href = '/your-url'` if needed.

If you need to handle html requests, you could always point your form to the url of your choice:

```
form_for @post, url: route_to_current_controller
```

Handle the create_post action on this controller and make sure your routes are set properly. The bad side of it is that you'll be handling posts creation in a different controller than your PostsController.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `render template: 'admins/newpost'`.  If you still get errors regarding missing template, check the format of the request against the available formats for views/admins/newpost.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to `render new`, when there are errors present.
The error message should be populated automagically by rails.

Also Can you verify there is a file called `newpost.html.erb` inside `app/views/dasharea` ?